# Laravel 4 Advanced Where - Unknown Column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, where-clause

I have a query which looks like this:

```
$items = Item::live()
  ->with('location')
  ->where('last_location_id', Input::get('last_location_id'))
  ->get();
```

The background of this is...

2 tables: Items & Cars.

The live scope is:

```
public function scopeLive($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('basic_car', function($q)
    {
        $q->whereNotNull('id')->where('sale_status', 'Live');

    });
}
```

This basically checks the cars table for a matching id to that of the items 'car_id' field and will run some where clauses on the cars table.

I now however want to check another field on the cars table, but using the Input::get('last_location_id') from the original query.

```
$items = Item::live()
  ->with('location')
  ->where('last_location_id', Input::get('last_location_id'))
  ->orWhere('ROW ON THE CARS TABLE' = Input::get('last_location_id'))
  ->get();
```

This does't work, then I tried:

```
$items = Item::live()
  ->with('location')
  ->where('last_location_id', Input::get('last_location_id'))
  ->orWhere(function($query)
  {
    $query->where('cars.Location', Input::get('last_location_id'));
  })
  ->get();
```

Which results in an unknown column 'cars.Location' error.

My next test was to create another scope:

```
public function scopeLiveTest($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('basic_car', function($q)
    {
        $q->whereNotNull('id')->where('sale_status', 'Live')->where('Location', 1); // hardcoded ID
    });
}
```

And replacing the live() scope with that works but I dont get the affect of the orWhere in the query itself and I also cannot specify a ID from the Input.

How can I do this?

Comment: That's why I don't really like Eloquent for anything more complex than a multiple join query. If you decide for using Fluent, you'll see it gets way easier

Comment: You're not the first person to say that! Have been having fun with Eloquent up until now but this is the first issue I have come across...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to scope like this:

```
$items = Item::liveAtLocation(Input::get('last_location_id'))
    ->orWhere(function( $query ) { // to get the OR working
        $query->live()
              ->with('location')
              ->where('last_location_id', Input::get('last_location_id'));
    })
    ->get();
```

And for the scope:

```
public function scopeLiveAtLocation($query, $location_id)
{
    return $query->whereHas('basic_car', function($q) use ($location_id)
    {
        $q->whereNotNull('id')->where('sale_status', 'Live')->where('Location', $location_id);
    });
}
```